# This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. on empty project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

My localhost does not load the page:

```
http://localhost:8080/ 
This site can’t be reached 
localhost refused to connect.
```

I have a brand new project and when I run the project I don't get any errors or see any errors but when I try to view using the localhost I see the above error

Here is the detail on my project.

Java version on my machine:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -version java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, and again I have nothing except this class which I run:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My POM file:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.2
 

com.example
demo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application log:

> 2021-01-16 19:24:07.268  INFO 23308 --- [           main]
> com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication
> using Java 13.0.2 on XPS8910 with PID 23308
> (C:\Users\nick\eclipse-workspace\demo\target\classes started by
> XPS89100 in C:\Users\nick\eclipse-workspace\demo) 2021-01-16
> 19:24:07.270  INFO 23308 --- [           main]
> com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set,
> falling back to default profiles: default 2021-01-16 19:24:07.740
> INFO 23308 --- [           main]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data
> JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2021-01-16 19:24:07.752  INFO 23308
> --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA
> repository interfaces. 2021-01-16 19:24:08.143  INFO 23308 --- [
> main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized
> with port(s): 8080 (http) 2021-01-16 19:24:08.151  INFO 23308 --- [
> main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service
> [Tomcat] 2021-01-16 19:24:08.151  INFO 23308 --- [           main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine:
> [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41] 2021-01-16 19:24:08.274  INFO 23308 --- [
> main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> embedded WebApplicationContext 2021-01-16 19:24:08.274  INFO 23308 ---
> [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root
> WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 961 ms 2021-01-16
> 19:24:08.429  INFO 23308 --- [           main]
> o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
> PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2021-01-16 19:24:08.473  INFO
> 23308 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    :
> HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final 2021-01-16
> 19:24:08.586  INFO 23308 --- [           main]
> o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate
> Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final} 2021-01-16 19:24:08.670  INFO 23308
> --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like spring application didn't start completely and freezes on starting Hikari Pool (last line in your log).

Hikari pool is a database connection pool. This probably means that the DB connection settings in your `application.properties` are incorrect and connection can't be established.

Can you verify that database is running and responding on the datasource URL you configured?